Setting up argocd metrics to get scraped at argocd-metrics:8082/metrics endpoint
Argocd v2.10 is managing applications but I need to update the templates to start scraping the metrics at the endpoint.
Application.metrics.enabled is already set to true.
How can the svc be created so that the metrics can be seen using a UI without port forwarding?
This document https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/ doesn’t show how to set this up to applications? A link to how to do that will be helpful!

not a lot to go on off of hits post, but looks like you need controller.metrics.enabled via https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/main/charts/argo-cd/templates/argocd-application-controller/metrics.yaml

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
